# Epoch & Unix Google Big Query Timestamp value for 1.601425865E9 How Convert Apex Code DateTime

Tags: apex

[image]

How Convert Timestamp to apex datetime
Im using for this format like
Long longtime = 1341828183000L;
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(longtime);
DateTime expected = DateTime.newInstance(2012, 7, 09, 3, 3, 3);
System.assertEquals(expected, dt);
this working for long value..but my scenario  for 1.601425865E9 this type of time stamp. not working long data type .how resolve this issue ,please help friends.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Long timestamp = ...;
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(timestamp);
```

See the [Datetime Class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm).

The sample code from there is:

```
Long longtime = 1341828183000L;
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(longtime);
DateTime expected = DateTime.newInstance(2012, 7, 09, 3, 3, 3);
System.assertEquals(expected, dt);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for help. Allredy I know this way 
Long timestamp = ...;
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(timestamp).
I need Timestamp value for 1.601425865E9  .How to Use Apex date time,
1.601425865E9  this code not working like datatypes long decimal float

Comment: Hi @GPRAJARATHINAM, Then do make your question clearer on what part is giving you the problem and some context.

Comment: Hi @Keith C ..
Long longtime =  1.601425865E9;
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(longtime);
Not Working  1.601425865E9 this type of timestamp ..How to resolve this issue.

Comment: string unixDatetime = '1.601425865E9';
system.debug(datetime.newinstance(long.valueOf(unixDateTime)));
Showing Error: System.TypeException: Invalid long: 1.601425865E9
How Resolve This error.im trying different way ..long decimal and float but not working plese help friends.

Comment: Per the documentation and error message, the argument needs to be a Long `newInstance(Long milliseconds)`. Somewhere the value is being turned into a floating point number; fix the problem there.

Comment: string unixDatetime = '1.601425865E9'; 

system.debug(datetime.millisecond(long.valueOf(unixDateTime)));
system.debug(datetime.millisecond(float.valueOf(unixDateTime)));
not working bro..Shwing error

Comment: @GPRAJARATHINAM Starting from a string version of a float is a bad idea. Start from a long. I'm ging to stop commenting now - good luck.